# Product Import: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product::saveRow() must be of the type array, boolean given

Tags: magento-1.9, error, importexport

For some reason, the import function is throwing errors on roughly 10% of the products I am attempting to import. The strange thing is I can export the CSV direct from Magento using the typical export all products profile and import that same exact CSV and the same bunch of products are throwing that error.

The exact error is :

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product::saveRow() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /home2/esdzone/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php on line 250 and defined in /home2/esdzone/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php on line 625

Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: The problem lies in special characters apparently. Not sure how or why they are breaking the import yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was opening the CSV file with excel. It is now resolved.